# Sqlite connecting to remote file using url C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

ive been trying to get my sqlite to read a remote file but is just flatout tells me this isnt supported is there a workaround for this ?

here is the function that gives the error

```
    public void Run(string sql,string check,string file)
      {
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        string test = "Data Source=" + file + ";Version=3;";
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(test);
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (check == "0")
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["name"] + "." + reader["TLD"]);
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           proxy = reader["proxyip"].ToString();
           check = "0";
        }
    }
```

error i get is "URI formats are not supported"

the file variable is filled by one of 2 values.

```
 string filelocal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\unblocker\\sites.db";
```

or

```
  string remotefile = "http://127.0.0.1/test.db";
```

the one that gives the error is the remote file.

Comment: What error do you get? the exact error.

Comment: Whats the exact value of the parameter file?

Answer (score 0):

The Connection string uses as a datasource the db file which is expected on your local file system, take a look at this [example code](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.html).

You can transorfm this using:

```
Uri uriFormatted = new Uri(file);
uriFormatted.AbsolutePath; // Try to use this value instead to call your function
```

**EDIT**

SQLite is a local standalone database, that is used for standalone software

Consider using [SQLitening](http://www.sqlitening.com/support/index.php):

SQLitening is a client/server implementation of the popular SQLite database.

Comment: well i can get it to work on local files but as soon as i start using a ip or url to access the files it dosn't work anymore. the reason i used 127.0.0.1 here is since im running a small server to test it.

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database and it is not intended to be used as a client-server. why do not you use SQLitening?

Comment: to be honest i had never heared of it XD.